# physical dimensions of the ipad screen

Tags: ipad

A client wants to have my app use real world dimensions (it's a modelling app). However, I am finding it difficult to get the dimensions of the screen itself, not the entire ipad unit (which are available from apple). I'll need this for all ipad versions including the mini. Does anyone have a source for these?

Comment: 9.7-inches?! Or am I missing something. This really isn't a programming question though...

Comment: I need width and height.

Comment: which iPad Model ... be specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7.76 inches high and 5.82 inches wide.
197 mm high by 147 mm wide

Comment: Height: 7.87 inches (200 mm); Width: 5.3 inches (134.7 mm) - i think

Comment: I don't think that can be right - it must be more like 6.28" x 4.71"